# RecyclerView is not refreshed in real time when adding data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i'm currently building a movies/series watchlist on android studio. The app has 2 tabs :

- A "Movies" tab where you can search movies/series and add them to a database
- A "Home" tab that would display the database (= the watchlist)

The issue I have is that when I add a movie to the database, the recyclerView in my Home tab is not refreshing in real time. I have to close the app and open it again in order to see the new added movies displayed. I implemented a notifyDataSetChanged() in my updataDataHome() function however it is still not refreshing in real time.

Here are the important parts of my code :

**A MovieManager for all my database functions :**

```
class MovieManager(private val context: Context) {

    private val dbHelper = DataBase.DatabaseHelper(context)


    fun addMovie(movie: MovieDB, homeAdapter: HomeAdapter) {
        val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        println("CONTEXT:$context")
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, movie.title)
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_ID, movie.id)
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_ADDED, movie.addedDate)
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_ORIGIN, movie.origin)
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_TYPE, movie.type)
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_USER, movie.user)
            put(DataBase.CollectionEntry.COLUMN_POSTER_PATH, movie.posterPath)
        }

        db.insert(DataBase.CollectionEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values)
        dbHelper.close()

        // Mettez à jour l'adaptateur Home après l'ajout du film
        //val updatedMovies = getMovies()
        //homeAdapter.updateDataHome(updatedMovies)
        //println("Updated movies:$updatedMovies")
    }

    fun clearDatabase() {
        val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM ${DataBase.CollectionEntry.TABLE_NAME}")
        dbHelper.close()
    }
}
```

**A MovieAdapter where i can click on a plus button to add a movie to the watchlist :**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val result = results[position]
        val dimX = 250
        val dimY = 350
        // Utilisez Picasso pour charger l'image à partir de l'URL du poster path
        Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${result.poster_path}")

            //.placeholder(R.drawable.sad_face)
            .error(R.drawable.not_found6)
            .resize(dimX, dimY)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.posterImageView)
        runOnUiThread{
            holder.addButton.setOnClickListener {
                val id: Int = result.id.toInt()
                val title: String = when {
                    result.title != null -> result.title
                    result.name != null -> result.name
                    else -> "Unknown title"
                }

                // Date d'ajout, origine, type et utilisateur (à adapter selon vos besoins)
                val addedDate: String = getCurrentDate()
                val origin: String = "API Source" // Remplacez par la source réelle de l'API
                val type: String = result.media_type ?: "Unknown type"
                val user: String = "Current User" // Remplacez par la logique pour obtenir l'utilisateur actuel
                val posterPath: String? = result.poster_path
                val movie = MovieDB(title, id, addedDate, origin, type, user, posterPath)

                // Ajoutez le film à la base de données
                movieManager.addMovie(movie, homeAdapter)
                //homeAdapter.updateDataHome(movieManager.getMovies())
                //notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
        }
    }

    fun runOnUiThread(action: () -> Unit) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.post { action.invoke() }
    }
```

**A HomeAdapter that contains the poster of the movie and its title (with the updateDataHome() function) :**

```
package fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.adapter

import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.R
import fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.database.MovieManager
import fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.model.MovieDB

class HomeAdapter(private val movieManager: MovieManager) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var movies: List<MovieDB> = emptyList()

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        // Initialisez les vues ici
        val posterImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posterImageViewHome)
        val titleTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextViewHome)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Créez et retournez le ViewHolder ici
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.database_result, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Associez les données aux vues ici
        val movie = movies[position]

        // Utilisez 'holder' pour accéder aux vues et associer les données du film
        Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.posterPath}")
            .resize(250, 360)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.posterImageView)

        holder.titleTextView.text = movie.title
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }

    fun updateDataHome(newMovies: List<MovieDB>) {
        runOnUiThread {
            movies = newMovies
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    fun runOnUiThread(action: () -> Unit) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.post { action.invoke() }
    }
}
```

**My HomeFragment that contains the adapter :**

```
package fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.R
import fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.adapter.HomeAdapter
import fr.cccq.mymultimedialist.database.MovieManager

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var recyclerViewHome: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapterHome: HomeAdapter
    private lateinit var movieManager: MovieManager

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        recyclerViewHome = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Initialisez le gestionnaire de base de données
        movieManager = MovieManager(requireContext())
        // Initialisez l'adaptateur pour l'onglet Home
        adapterHome = HomeAdapter(movieManager)
        // Initialisez le RecyclerView
        recyclerViewHome.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        recyclerViewHome.adapter = adapterHome

        // Chargez les films à partir de la base de données
        val moviesFromDatabase = movieManager.getMovies()

        // Mettez à jour l'adaptateur avec les films de la base de données
        runOnUiThread {
            adapterHome.updateDataHome(moviesFromDatabase)
            adapterHome.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        // Affichez les films dans la console
        displayMoviesFromDatabase()
        //movieManager.clearDatabase()
    }

    fun runOnUiThread(action: () -> Unit) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.post { action.invoke() }
    }
    

    private fun displayMoviesFromDatabase() {
        val movies = movieManager.getMovies()
        for (movie in movies) {
            println("Movie from Database: ${movie.title}, ID: ${movie.id}, Added Date: ${movie.addedDate}, Origin: ${movie.origin}, Type: ${movie.type}, User: ${movie.user}")
        }
    }

}
```

Could you please help me with my issue ?
Many thanks!

I have tried to put the updateDataHome() + notifyDataSetChanged() in different places but it didn't make any difference..

Comment: Why is the logic in addMovie inside the manager class commented out? You are passing your adapter there as well.

Comment: @tomerpacific I tried to put it there in order to see if it solved the problem but it didn't make any change so i commented it